# Can play store in-app purchases be transferred among devices if I use the same Google account to make the purchases?

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I recently purchased "Minecraft pocket edition" from playstore with my Google account. Me and my girlfriend are both using the same Google account and hence we have both been able to play the game. Recently I've been thinking of buying some texture packs and mash-up packs. If I do in-app purchase of these, will it only be available to me or can we both use it?(since we're both using the same Google account)

PS : We both have different Xbox accounts which we use to play the game, but the Google account is the same

Comment: How expensive are these?  I would recommend buying one inexpensive one and seeing what happens.

Comment: The dollar value of the texture packs come around $2.99 each after conversion. The mashup packs are around $5.99 each.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about Minecraft or Xbox accounts but as far as Google accounts go, anything purchased on one devise is available on all of the other devices registered to that account.

Comment: I understand that and that's why my girlfriend and I used the same Google account to purchase the app. We both have access to it now by paying just once. However we both had to create an Xbox account when we launched the game. This has been bugging me as I don't know whether the in-app purchases will be credited to my Google account(in which case we can both have access to it), or to my Xbox account(in which case only I'll have access to it).There wasn't much info on Playstore either regarding non-stop purchase